# NextJS with express - separate or together

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I'm developing the **NextJS** app with express, postgresql, is it good approach to put the *API* endpoints in the next.js `pages/api` folder? Or should it be separated?
I thought about separating it to client/server folders, but I don't know how to share the cookies between 2 ports on localhost (I want to use httpOnly cookie for authentication), because my server was running on *3030*, and **nextjs** app on *3000*, so I thought that maybe I should keep everyting in **next.js** and create endpoints in pages/api.

Which one is the better solution?